# Memory delete failed in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a morse code program.

When I pass the word, it allocates the memory of a char* length and for each letter allocates memory of morse letters length. It works fine as I have tested it, but when I added the funciont `clear()` to delete allocated memory, it crashes `(_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE).`
Could you tell me where I made a mistake?

The first part,

```
class morse
{
private:
convert converter;
.
.
```

constructor:

```
morse::morse()
    :converter()
{
}
```

and some conversion methods

```
class convert
{
protected:
    char** letter;
    int size;
.
.
.


convert::convert()
    :letter(0), size(20)
{
    letter = new char*[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        letter[i] = new char[4];
}

convert::~convert()
{
    clear();
}

void convert::clear()
{
    if (size != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[] letter[i];
        delete[] letter;
    }

    size = 0;
    letter = new char*;
}


void convert::translate(const char * x)
{
    clear();
    size = strlen(x);
    letter = new char*[strlen(x)+1];



    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++)
    {
        switch (x[i])
        {
        case 'a': case 'A':
            save(i, "._");
            break;
        case 'b': case 'B':
            save(i , "_...");
            break;
        case 'c': case 'C':
            save(i, "_._.");
            break;
.
.
.
.


void convert::save(int i, const char * lol)
{
    letter[i] = new char[strlen(lol) + 1];
    letter[i] = const_cast<char*>(lol);
}
```

It works fine once, it deletes memory allocated by constructor, and translates the whole word easly, but when I give  it another one it shows deletion error when it reaches `clear()` once again

Comment: Your `translate` and `save` functions would lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the `save` function where you have this:

```
letter[i] = new char[strlen(lol) + 1];
letter[i] = const_cast<char*>(lol);
```

The first line make `letter[i]` point to some memory you allocate. Then you directly make it point to the literal strings you pass to the `save` function. And the literal strings aren't something you could `delete[]`.

This is basically equivalent to

```
int l;
l = 5;
l = 10;
```

and then wondering why `l` is not equal to `5` anymore.

The solution to *this* problem is to not have the second assignment, and to use the [`std::strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) function to copy the string.

Or, better yet, not use pointers at all, and instead use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Then you wouldn't have to worry about memory leaks as well.

Answer (score 0):

(Removed, I was incorrect.  I don't see how to delete this myself)

Comment: At the bottom there should be links that say `share` `edit` `delete`